# Performing histology on undecalcified tissue

Tags: cell-biology, histology, calcium, dissection

Performing histology on tissue containing calcification - without performing decalcification of the tissue - is a challenging problem. There are currently a few methods to overcome these challenges including epoxy embedment, methacrylate embedment, and stabilization of tissue followed by partial decalcification. However there are drawbacks or limitations to each method as each may require specific infrastructure to perform effectively, such as a specific style of microtome.

Besides these challenges, how might you approach sectioning of calcified tissue with the aim of preservation the soft-hard interface along any calcified region? The following are objectives and demands of a successful technique:

- *objective 1*: perform sectioning of a tissue containing thin wall calcification while preserving the spatial arrangement of soft
  tissues in the region adjacent to calcified tissue - analogous to
  periosteum-bone interface
- *objective 2*: preserve molecular composition and spatial arrangement throughout process
- *objective 3*: produce thin sections
- *demand 1*: limit as much as possible any decalcification of to-be-sectioned tissue
- *demand 2*: perform technique with minimal specialty equipment
- *demand 3*: no paraffin

I will provide an initial option to begin: Tissue will be embedded in a high monomer content neutral aqueous polymer solution and chemically crosslinked following adequate diffusion time (akin to CLARITY protocol). Tissue will be cryostabilized and placed on a cryostat near -40 for sectioning.

Comment: This seems more like a research-level question someone might spend several years developing a PhD thesis to address; the techniques you mention exist because they're the best that people have come up with. If someone came up with something better that lacked the drawbacks, that's what everyone would do instead. Have you attempted the option you propose? What happened? I think it's okay to have this question here in case someone does have an answer, but I'm highly doubtful.

Comment: I think thats the purpose of asking the question isn't it? As well, getting answers which may not necessarily outright provide a method that encompasses the objectives and demands but might provide ideas toward a successful method would still be useful.